# Mercurial Push Error on Google Code Value Error

Tags: mercurial, push, dvcs, google-code

I am trying to learn to use mercurial by pushing onto Google code.

I have two `.hgrc files`: One file is located `$PROJECT_DIR/.hg/.hrgc` and `$HOME/.hgrc`. I have two separate files because I did not want to put the password out on the central repository.

Here is the content of `$PROJECT_DIR/.hg/.hrgc`:

```
[ui]
usermane=Venkat S. Rao <vrao423@gmail.com>
verbose=true

[paths]
default-push =https:vrao423:gc4yy3vB3mc4@//personal-site423.googlecode.com/hg/us
```

Here is the content of `$HOME/.hgrc`:

```
[ui]
username= Venkat Rao <vrao423@gmail.com>
verbose=True

[auth]
project.prefix=https://personal-site423.googlecode.com/hg/
password=###
username=vrao423
```

---

For username I have my Gmail id.

I can commit changes to my local repository, but when I try hg push I get this error.

```
** unknown exception encountered, details follow
** report bug details to http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/
** or mercurial@selenic.com
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.4.3)
** Extensions loaded: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hg", line 27, in 
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 16, in run
    sys.exit(dispatch(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 30, in dispatch
    return _runcatch(u, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 46, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(ui, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 454, in _dispatch
    return runcommand(lui, repo, cmd, fullargs, ui, options, d)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 324, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 505, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 459, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 453, in 
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/util.py", line 386, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/commands.py", line 2345, in push
    other = hg.repository(cmdutil.remoteui(repo, opts), dest)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/hg.py", line 63, in repository
    repo = _lookup(path).instance(ui, path, create)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 263, in instance
    inst.between([(nullid, nullid)])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 184, in between
    d = self.do_read("between", pairs=n)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 128, in do_read
    fp = self.do_cmd(cmd, **args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 80, in do_cmd
    resp = self.urlopener.open(urllib2.Request(cu, data, headers))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/url.py", line 455, in https_open
    self.auth = self.pwmgr.readauthtoken(req.get_full_url())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/url.py", line 141, in readauthtoken
    group, setting = key.split('.', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Please help me. I have tried reading the hgrc man but that is just gibberish.

Thank You
Venkat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a Mercurial developer. Please report problems with our [man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) on the [mailinglist](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MailingLists) or on our [bugtracker](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/). I would love to hear from you so that we can make the man page better, so please write to us and tell us which part you found to be "gibberish".

In this particular case, the problem is that you need to write your [auth section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) like this:

```
[auth]
project.prefix=https://personal-site423.googlecode.com/hg/
project.password=###
project.username=vrao423
```

where I would replace `project` with `googlecode` or something similar. We should of course report something sensible instead of a traceback and I can see that we already fixed [this particular bug](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue2056) in Mercurial 1.5.

Comment: thank you...this fixes the problem. I will add a detailed list of gibberish after I return from work.

Comment: user416816: cool -- please send the list to mercurial@selenic.com instead of putting it here. That is much more helpful to the project.

Comment: Venkat: Thanks for sending the mail to our mailinglist: http://mercurial.markmail.org/message/2ocbcez2smuc6zec